# How to call protected constructor in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

How to call protected constructor?

```
public class Foo{
  public Foo(a lot of arguments){}
  protected Foo(){}
}
var foo=???
```

This obviously fails test:

```
public class FooMock:Foo{}
var foo=new FooMock();
Assert(typeof(Foo), foo.GetType());
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can only call that from a subclass, basically. Your `FooMock` class will already be calling the protected constructor, because it's equivalent to:

```
public class FooMock : Foo
{
    public FooMock() : base() // Call the protected base constructor
    {
    }
}
```

However, your assertion will fail because the type of object referred to be `foo` is `FooMock`, not `Foo`.

An assertion of the form `foo is Foo` *will* pass though.

You can't construct an instance of just `Foo` by calling the protected constructor directly. The point of it being protected instead of public is to ensure that it's only called by subclasses (or within the text of `Foo` itself).

It's possible that you could call it with reflection within a full trust context, but I'd urge you not to do so.

Comment: "but I'd urge you not to do so" why not? I need that for test. maybe that makes sense then after all?

Comment: @Arnis L.: At that point you're doing little more than coming up with a hack to make a test pass, which is about as useful as not writing the test at all.  This is a good time to step back and take a look at _why_ this constructor is `protected`, as it implies that the behavior you seek (and are testing) is explicitly unsupported (and, thus, not testable).

Comment: @Arnis: Usually if you need to bypass the accessibility model with reflection, that suggests you shouldn't be trying to get access to the member in question - or you should increase the accessibility yourself.

Comment: @David it's more like creating test fixture. I'm not testing Foo itself. hence - I'm not interested to satisfy all needs what Foo normally asks for neither loosen them up.

Comment: @Arnis: You may want to consider using `protected internal` and then using `InternalsVisibleTo` to allow your test assembly to access internals of your production assembly.

Comment: @Jon Skeet testing problems shouldn't mold testable code. at least - not in this direction.

Comment: I use protected constructors for JSON.Net all the time.. I prefer JSON.Net call a much more minimal constructor than im gonna call in code.. Writing a test to very the JsonConstructors wont just blow up seems pretty reasonable

Answer (score 35):

Call parameterless protected/private constructor:

```
Foo foo = (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo), true);
```

Call non-public constructor with parameters:

```
  var foo = (Foo)typeof(Foo)
    .GetConstructor(
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance, 
      null, 
      new[] { typeof(double) }, 
      null
    )
    .Invoke(new object[] { 1.0 });

  class Foo
  {
     private Foo(double x){...}
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to cause a protected constructor to be called is to derive from the class and have the derived class delegate to it or to have a static method create it or some other internal method.

EDIT: What the Skeet said!

Answer (score 2):

Serj-Tm answered adequately but Activator can do it too:

```
var foo = (Foo) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo), 
               BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, 
               null, 
               new object[] { 2.0 }, 
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a `protected` method - although you can call an `internal` one (using `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute). You need to expose it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid repeated reflection cost, you can use expressions.
Here is an example of calling a private constructor with a string value.

```
    private static Func<string, T> CreateInstanceFunc()
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructors(flags).Single(
            ctors =>
            {
                var parameters = ctors.GetParameters();
                return parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(string);
            });
        var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "value");
        var body = Expression.New(ctor, value);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, T>>(body, value);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }
```

Save the cost of compiling the function multiple times by storing it in a static field.

```
private static readonly Lazy<Func<string, T>> CreateInstance = new Lazy<Func<string, T>>(CreateInstanceFunc);
```

Now you can create the object with

```
CreateInstance.Value("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to explicitly call the constructor of you base class in your subclass, you have to use the keyword **[base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help:

abstract parent class:

```
 public abstract class Animal
    {

        private string name;

        public Animal(string name)
        {

            this.Name = name;
        }

        public Animal() { }
        public string Name
        {

            get { return this.name; }

            set { this.name = value; }

        }

        public virtual void talk()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hi,I am  an animal");

        }


    }
```

class with protected constructor:

```
public class Lion : Animal
    {
        private string yahoo;

        protected Lion(string name) : base(name)
        {

            this.Yahoo = "Yahoo!!!";
        }

        public string Yahoo
        {
            get
            {
                return yahoo;
            }

            set
            {
                yahoo = value;
            }
        }

        public Lion() { }
    }
```

class Kiara derived from Lion class :

```
 public class Kiara : Lion
    {

        public Kiara(string name) : base(name)
        {

        }

        public override void talk()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("HRRRR I'm a Kiara");

        }

        public Kiara() { }

    }
```

class Simba derived from Lion class :

```
    public class Simba : Lion
    {

        public Simba(string name) : base(name)
        {

        }

        public override void talk()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("HRRRR I'm a {0}  and this is my daughter:{1} {2}", 
            new Simba("Simba").Name, 
            new Kiara("Kiara").Name, 
            new Simba("Simba").Yahoo);
        }


        public Simba() { }

    }
```

implementation in main function:

```
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Animal lion = new Simba();
            lion.Name = "Simba";
            lion.talk(); 
            Animal lion1 = new Kiara();
            lion1.Name = "Kiara";
            lion1.talk();
        }
```