# Calling Protected constructors of a class in c#

Tags: c#, class, constructor, protected

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call protected constructor in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365745/how-to-call-protected-constructor-in-c)

I searched for a solution of my problem.
Actually I don't know if it is possible or not. Please help me.

```
namespace namespace1
{
    namespace namespace1a
    {
        public class classa
        {
            protected classa(string i) //protected constructor
            {
                //Do something
            }
            public classa() //public constructor
            {
                //Do something
            }

        }
    }

    namespace namespace1b
    {
        public class classb
        {
            classa i = new classa(); // calls public constructor of classa

            classa j = new classa("hi"); //Invalid. How to call the protected constructor of classa
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call the protected constructor of "**classa**" from "**classb**", How to do that? Please help me.

Comment: Only possible if `classb` derives from `classa`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call protected constructor in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365745/how-to-call-protected-constructor-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

- `classa` and `classb` are in the same assembly
- You are authoring both class
- You are trying to protect `classa`'s constructor.

then you can declare the constructor as `protected internal` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to get a reference to the constructor you want to invoke from the type's metadata:

```
var ctor = typeof(classa).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
```

Once you have a reference to the constructor you can invoke it, passing in the arguments you want to give the constructor as an array of objects:

```
var instance = (classa)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { "Chicken butt" });
```

That being said, the constructor is probably protected for a reason and using reflection to circumvent encapsulation of a type's members is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A safe way to do this would be to add a proxy class that inherits from `classb` with a public constructor taking a string.  The protected contract is well-defined.

```
class bproxy : classb
{
     public bproxy(string x) : base(x) {...}
}
```

---

An alternative is to use reflection.  Quite honestly **I don't recommend doing this** because when an author sets a constructor as protected, it's intended to only be used by itself and derived classes.  You are also tightly coupled to a "contract" that is not explicitly defined.

That being said, this *should* work for you though it will break as soon as the author changes the non-guaranteed part of the contract (**USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**):

```
var constructor = typeof(classa).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var b = constructor.First().Invoke(new object[] {"hi"});
```

Comment: -1 for giving OP a big red button and then telling him not to press it.

Comment: @Servy Giving warnings when showing how to do something dangerous is a bad idea?

Comment: @cadrell0 No, it would be better to not show someone how to do something dangerous in the first place as opposed to saying, "you need to inherit from the class to use that constructor" and ignoring any hacks to access it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless classb derives from classa. Protected makes the constructor visible only to the class itself and every class that derives from classa.

Take a look here: [Protected C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365745/how-to-call-protected-constructor-in-c).

except for deriving from classa, reflection is a usefull option (by quering the constructors of the tpye, and then running the suitable one, as explained in one of the answers in the link provided)